# Class template value without template arguments error

Tags: c++, templates

I have some code:

```
template<typename Container = std::vector> // there is error
class SomeClass {
    struct SomeDataStructure {
        int a;
        float b;
    };

    Container<SomeDataStructure> container; // and there
};
```

I want to pass template class type in template arguments of other template class.
In this example, I want to pass `std::vector` to `SomeClass` and define `Container`(`std::vector`) of private structure `SomeDataStructure`.
But I'm getting errors(MSVC compiler) `C2059` and `C2238`.
How can I solve it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: when facing a compiler error, please include the complete error message in the question. Error codes are specific to compilers, while the problem with your code is the same with any compiler. Anyhow, you need a template tempalte paramter as explained in the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need template template parameters:

```
template<template<class, class...> class Container = std::vector>
```